# Get Child Records with getRecordUI in LWC

Tags: rest-api, lightning-web-components

Trying to child records through the getRecordUI

```
@wire(getRecordUi, { recordIds: '$recordId', childRelationships: 'PREFIX__OBJECT__c.PREFIX__CHILD_RELATIONSHIP_NAME__r', layoutTypes: 'Compact', modes: 'View' }) wiredResult(result) {}
```

When i run this off the rest api

```
/services/data/v45.0/ui-api/record-ui/a686C0000004EvRQAU?childRelationships=PREFIX__OBJECT__c.PREFIX__CHILD_RELATIONSHIP_NAME__r
```

It works and pulls the child records. But in Lightning despite it using the same API it doesn't pull any records.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `But in Lightning despite it using the same API it doesn't pull any records.` Please paste a screenshot of the `Response` captured in Chrome Network tab of the DevTools for the same request.